# In MySQL, how can I concatenate multiple rows and then search on that data?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Struggling a bit with MySQL. I've found the `GROUP_CONCAT` function which looks right for my needs, but I can't work out how to use it. What I'd like to do is search in several columns as well as the concat column; so if any of the columns equal my search term (`%a%` in this example) it should be returned. I've worked out how to return the concatenated genre string but I can't work out how to search on it.

```
SELECT albumArtworkURL, albumName, albumID, 
  b.artistID AS ArtistID, b.artistName AS ArtistName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.songGenre separator ',') AS genres
FROM album
LEFT JOIN artist b ON album.albumArtist = b.artistID
LEFT JOIN song c ON albumID = c.songOnAlbum
WHERE albumName LIKE '%a%' OR albumYear LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY albumArtworkURL, albumName, albumID, ArtistID, ArtistName
ORDER BY albumYear ASC, albumName ASC
```

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search on the result of the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, then you could wrap your query in another select:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT albumArtworkURL, 
    albumName, 
    albumID, 
    b.artistID AS ArtistID, 
    b.artistName AS ArtistName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.songGenre separator ',') AS genres
  FROM album
  LEFT JOIN artist b 
    ON album.albumArtist = b.artistID
  LEFT JOIN song c 
    ON albumID = c.songOnAlbum
  GROUP BY albumArtworkURL, albumName, albumID, ArtistID, ArtistName
) src
WHERE albumName LIKE '%a%' 
  OR albumYear LIKE '%a%'
  OR genres LIKE  '%a%'
ORDER BY albumYear ASC, albumName ASC
```

But unless I am missing something in your explanation, I don't know why you can't just search on the `songGenre` instead of the concat version of it:

```
SELECT albumArtworkURL, 
  albumName, 
  albumID, 
  b.artistID AS ArtistID, 
  b.artistName AS ArtistName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.songGenre separator ',') AS genres
FROM album
LEFT JOIN artist b 
  ON album.albumArtist = b.artistID
LEFT JOIN song c 
  ON albumID = c.songOnAlbum
WHERE albumName LIKE '%a%' 
  OR albumYear LIKE '%a%'
  OR songGenre LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY albumArtworkURL, albumName, albumID, ArtistID, ArtistName
ORDER BY albumYear ASC, albumName ASC
```

Comment: i thought the same thing about a predicate on songGenre; the problem with that is that all of the songGenre values (that don't match) won't appear in the GROUP_CONCAT output.

Comment: your first query demonstrates how to put a predicate on the output from GROUP_CONCAT, which is the question he asked.  But that approach makes me shudder, at the prospect of the performance implications. Your second query has a decent probability of being much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You raise a good point about performance, something I hadn't considered. It isn't critical that the `GROUP_CONCAT` is complete, just that the search term matches one (or more) term in that set; therefore I think I'll go with the second option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

To search the result from the GROUP_CONCAT, that predicate has to be in a HAVING clause, which  should appear after the GROUP BY and before the ORDER BY, e.g.

```
HAVING genres LIKE '%a%'
```

Note that the value of the GROUP_CONCAT expression is not available when the rows are being accessed, that is, when the predicates in the ON and WHERE clause are evaluated. That expression is not available until AFTER the resultset is prepared, which is why that predicate needs to be in the HAVING clause. (The HAVING clause gets processed very late in the execution plan, before the LIMIT clause is applied, and possibly before a sort operation to satisfy an ORDER BY.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although this doesn't solve my problem I've upvoted for your comments on the accepted answer. :-)